# аналог avformat_open_input со строкой вместо файла

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Есть строка с SDP информацией, содержащей всю нужную информацию по кодекам. Не хочется создавать для нее файл, передавать его в avformat_open_input, а затем удалять и так каждый раз.  А надо бы разбирать sdp-строку и настраивать тип входящего кодека и проч. без создания файла.
Я не нашел функционала ffmpeg, который бы со строки инитил бы кодеки. Может, кто-то знает его?
Или придется писать свой парсер и вручную настраивать кодеки?

Comment: SDP прост как веник, это текстовые файлы с парами ключ/значение

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @Cerbo да, но из-за его простоты я и не хочу писать его в файл для использования. Он генерируется в const string& и его хочу передавать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотря что понимать под нужным функционалом. Ты можешь созать свой AVIO контекст, а он, в качестве источника данных, может хоть базу данных, хоть общую память, хоть просто кусок памяти использовать.

Курить:

- [avio_alloc_context()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_8h.html#a853f5149136a27ffba3207d8520172a5)
- AVFormatContext::pb
- [avformat_open_input()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga31d601155e9035d5b0e7efedc894ee49)

Т.е. алгоритм ваших действий будет примерно такой:

1. Аллоцировать `AVFormatContext` (`avformat_alloc_context()`)
2. Аллоцировать `AVIOContext` с нужными функциями, и структурой контекста
3. Присвоить `AVFormatContext::pb` значение вашего контекста IO
4. Вызвать `avformat_open_input()` где первым параметром передать указатель на ваш, уже аллоцированный, контекст формата - он любезно им воспользуется.

При вызове вашей процедуры чтения вполне возможно, что запросится только часть данных, поэтому нужно где-то хранить позицию чтения (opaque вам в помощь) и контроллировать границу данных (когда у вас осталось, допустим, 2 байта, а запросили буфер 1024 - записать только 2 и вернуть реальное число записанный байт, т.е. снова - 2).

А вот и рабочий, компилируемый (GCC 4.9, FFmpeg 2.8.6) пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

using namespace std;

static const char* SDP_DATA = R"(
v=0
o=- 1376063087593 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
m=audio 50008 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.196
a=rtcp:50009 IN IP4 192.168.2.196
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=sendrecv
m=video 50010 RTP/AVP 120
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.196
a=rtcp:50011 IN IP4 192.168.2.196
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-fb:* nack
a=rtcp-fb:* ccm fir
)";

struct SdpOpaque
{
    using Vector = std::vector<uint8_t>;
    Vector           data;
    Vector::iterator pos;
};

int sdp_read(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int size) noexcept
{
    assert(opaque);
    assert(buf);
    auto octx = static_cast<SdpOpaque*>(opaque);

    if (octx->pos == octx->data.end()) {
        return 0;
    }

    auto dist = static_cast<int>(std::distance(octx->pos, octx->data.end()));
    auto count = std::min(size, dist);

    std::copy(octx->pos, octx->pos + count, buf);
    octx->pos += count;

    return count;
}

int sdp_open(AVFormatContext **pctx, const char *data, AVDictionary **options) noexcept
{
    assert(pctx);
    *pctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    assert(*pctx);

    const size_t avioBufferSize = 4096;
    auto avioBuffer = static_cast<uint8_t*>(av_malloc(avioBufferSize));
    auto opaque = new SdpOpaque();

    opaque->data = SdpOpaque::Vector(data, data + strlen(data));
    opaque->pos  = opaque->data.begin();

    auto pbctx = avio_alloc_context(avioBuffer, avioBufferSize, 0, opaque, sdp_read, nullptr, nullptr);
    assert(pbctx);

    (*pctx)->pb = pbctx;

    auto infmt = av_find_input_format("sdp");

    return avformat_open_input(pctx, "memory.sdp", infmt, options);
}

void sdp_close(AVFormatContext **fctx) noexcept
{
    assert(fctx);
    auto ctx = *fctx;

    // Opaque can be non-POD type, free it before and assign to null
    auto opaque = static_cast<SdpOpaque*>(ctx->pb->opaque);
    delete opaque;
    ctx->pb->opaque = nullptr;

    avio_close(ctx->pb);
    avformat_close_input(fctx);
}

int main()
{
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    AVFormatContext *sdpctx = nullptr;
    sdp_open(&sdpctx, SDP_DATA, nullptr);

    av_dump_format(sdpctx, 0, "memory.sdp", 0);
    // Copy settings to target context from SDP context:
    /*
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sdpctx->nb_streams; ++i) {
        AVStream *st = avformat_new_stream(otherctx, nullptr);
        st->id = i;
        avcodec_copy_context(st->codec, sdpctx->streams[i]->codec);
        st->time_base = sdpctx->streams[i]->time_base;
    }
    */

    sdp_close(&sdpctx);
    return 0;
}
```

После запуска выводит:

```
Input #0, sdp, from 'memory.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: vp8, none, 90k tbn
```

Собственно, что и описано в SDP.

Comment: Набросал по Вашей инструкции код, но что-то пошло не так. Вот вырезка:
`int open(const string& sdp){
 AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx=NULL;
 AVIOContext *avio_ctx=NULL;
 uint8_t *avio_ctx_buffer=NULL;
 size_t  avio_ctx_buffer_size=4096;
 struct buffer_data bd={0};
 std::vector<uint8_t>SDPvector(sdp.begin(),sdp.end());
 bd.ptr=&SDPvector[0];
 bd.size=4096;
 fmt_ctx=avformat_alloc_context();
 av_malloc(avio_ctx_buffer_size);
 avio_ctx=avio_alloc_context(avio_ctx_buffer,avio_ctx_buffer_size,
 0,&bd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
 fmt_ctx->pb=avio_ctx;
 //падает
 ret=avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx,NULL,NULL,NULL);`

Comment: `struct buffer_data { uint8_t *ptr; size_t size; };`  не вместилось в начало первого комментария.  после метки //падает вызывается завершение программы. Т.е. После выполнения следующей строчки.  P.S. местами пытался сокращать код из-за недостатка места.  Кстати, на сайте ffmpeg есть пример кода, откуда я и брал эту часть, но он не работает. В частности `avio_ctx_buffer=av_malloc(avio_ctx_buffer_size);`, но справа void* [ссылка] http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_reading_8c-example.html#a20

Comment: Опубликуй код на http://pastebin.com или другом схожем сервисе с включенной подсветкой синтаксиса :) Не думаю, что раньше своего завтра посмотрю. Лучше накидай ПОЛНЫЙ компилируемый пример. Мне так проще будет дать тебе более точный и верный ответ :)

Comment: И ещё скажи, какой язык, я то я увидел и NULL и std::vector...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2iMhrCGh  язык-то С++, все NULL и тд взяты из библиотеки ffmpeg. К сожалению, не могу кинуть полный компилируемый пример, слишком много выйдет. Но из того, что по ссылке, должно стать понятно(как мне кажется). Работаю в VS2013 и выдает ошибку error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static int __cdecl Class::read_packet(void *,unsigned char *,int)" (?read_packet@Class@@CAHPAXPAEH@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall Class::open(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)"

Comment: за VS не скажу, не работаю, но, обычно, такие ошибки - что-то не подключил, какую-то либу.

Comment: И дай, пожалуйста, пример SDP

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PDqnXeDC пример SDP и в конце ссылка на вики по SDP протоколам.
Все либы подключил и до этого все было нормально (когда из файла читалось), прогуглил ошибку на msdn(справка по VS) скорее всего ошибка в static read_packet. Т.е. К ffmpeg мало отношения имеет ошибка. Но другого пути в ffmpeg для решения чтения из строки нет(

Comment: У вас, похоже, не сильное владение языком. Как минимум, в С++ более строгие требования к типам, поэтому приводить `void*` к нужному - обязательно. Опубликовал рабочий компилябельный пример.

Comment: Спасибо! Этот метод несколько менее легкопонимаемый, но, походу, рабочий. VS выдает warnings разные, но это уже решаемо. Не знаю, как еще Вам плюс поставить.

Comment: Вопрос "понимаемости" весьма субъективен :)

Comment: Еще один вопрос появился: в строчке `AVStream *st = avformat_new_stream(otherctx, nullptr);` что такое `otherctx`?

Comment: Контекст SDP содержит только информацию, но не данные. В данном примере под `otherctx` подразумевается другой контекст к которому применяются данные параметры стрима и кодеков. Но как, конкретно, у вас оно будет использоваться - я не знаю. Возможно это будет входной поток, как в RTSP, и данные параметры подскажут на каких портах слушать RTP/RTCP пакеты. А может и выходной поток, если мы хотим просто скопировать пакеты без перекодировки или сделать кодировку с определёнными параметрами.